# How to obtain text from anchor tag using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following inline styled anchor that I need the text from.

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="CourseModels">
    <A style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #0077cc 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT: #0077cc 1px solid; PADDING-BOTTOM: 1px; LINE-HEIGHT: 1.6em; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #0077cc; MARGIN: 3px; PADDING-LEFT: 3px; PADDING-RIGHT: 3px; COLOR: #dedede; FONT-SIZE: 1.2em; BORDER-TOP: #0077cc 1px solid; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; BORDER-RIGHT: #0077cc 1px solid; PADDING-TOP: 1px" id="linkModel1" class="anchorModel" href="../ProductPage/Page.aspx?id=PS111&amp;div=dvr">PS111</A>
    <A style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #0077cc 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT: #0077cc 1px solid; PADDING-BOTTOM: 1px; LINE-HEIGHT: 1.6em; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #0077cc; MARGIN: 3px; PADDING-LEFT: 3px; PADDING-RIGHT: 3px; COLOR: #dedede; FONT-SIZE: 1.2em; BORDER-TOP: #0077cc 1px solid; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; BORDER-RIGHT: #0077cc 1px solid; PADDING-TOP: 1px" id="linkModel2" class="anchorModel" href="../ProductPage/Page.aspx?id=PS112&amp;div=dvr">PS112</A>
    <A style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #0077cc 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT: #0077cc 1px solid; PADDING-BOTTOM: 1px; LINE-HEIGHT: 1.6em; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #0077cc; MARGIN: 3px; PADDING-LEFT: 3px; PADDING-RIGHT: 3px; COLOR: #dedede; FONT-SIZE: 1.2em; BORDER-TOP: #0077cc 1px solid; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; BORDER-RIGHT: #0077cc 1px solid; PADDING-TOP: 1px" id="linkModel3" class="anchorModel" href="../ProductPage/Page.aspx?id=PS113&amp;div=dvr">PS113</A>
    (...dynamically created..)
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Using:

```
var m = $('.CourseModels', $(this).closest("tr")).html();

alert(m.text());
```

This produces "Object doesn't support this property or method".

Comment: Can you post the full jQuery code you tried? And FYI IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: Elements should have unique IDs.

Comment: Even with the bad mistake mentioned above, it still works: http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/L80rb85c/1/

Comment: I corrected that. Sorry.

Comment: `id=linkModel1 class=anchorModel` - the values should be wrapped with quotes like this `id="linkModel1" class="anchorModel"`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may help you

```
var text1 = $('#linkModel1').html();
var text2 = $('#linkModel2').html();
var text3 = $('#linkModel3').html();

console.log(text1, text2, text3);
```

Edit 1:

Ok, you can use this:

```
$('.CourseModels a').each(function(index, element) {
  console.log($(element).text());
});
```

A working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zLLL4f9m/)

Comment: This gives me [object Object]